# Using Tycho, how do I build a Feature that includes other Features that I have built and deployed on my p2 repository

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I want to build a Feature that is made up only of other Features that I have also built using Tycho.

So, lets say the aggregator Feature is com.myurl.feature.agg

In its feature.xml file, I have a couple of entries that look like this...

```
<feature>

    ...

   <includes
     id="com.myurl.feature.foo"
     version="1.0.12.qualifier"
     search-location="both"/>

   <includes
     id="com.myurl.feature.bar"
     version="1.1.4.qualifier"
     search-location="both"/>
</feature>
```

The two features included are successfully built and reside on a p2 repository that I have access to and have verified that works fine.

My pom file for the com.myurl.feature.agg has the necessary reference to the p2 repository, and I can see that it finds the included features successfully because the output from the mvn clean install command... shows that is is "fetching" what looks like the correct bundles that make up the features com.myurl.feature.foo and com.myurl.feature.bar.

But, shortly after that I get this error.

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.myurl.feature.agg.feature.group 1.1.5.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.myurl.feature.agg.feature.group 1.1.5.qualifier requires 'com.myurl.feature.bar.feature.group [1.1.4,1.1.5)' but it could not be found
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from com.myurl.feature.agg.feature.group 1.1.5.qualifier to com.myurl.feature.bar.feature.group [1.1.4,1.1.5).; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.] ->
[Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from com.myurl.feature.agg.feature.group 1.1.5.qualifier to com.myurl.feature.bar.feature.group [1.1.4,1.1.5).; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from com.myurl.feature.agg.feature.group 1.1.5.qualifier to com.myurl.feature.bar.feature.group [1.1.4,1.1.5).; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.AbstractResolutionStrategy.newResolutionException(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.ProjectorResolutionStrategy.resolve(ProjectorResolutionStrategy.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.AbstractResolutionStrategy.resolve(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.doResolvePlatform(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.resolveDependencies(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:271)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    ... 11 more
```

Can anyone help me figure out why Tycho is not finding this dependency, even though it seems that the dependency is readily available and found successfully early on during the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.  The fact that I had a feature containing features that were available on a p2 repository was not the cause of my problem.  You can definitely do that using Tycho.

My issue was with one of the features that was on the p2 repository.  The guilty feature was com.myurl.feature.bar.

I had done something wrong with the way I built or deployed the p2 repository.  I'm not sure what it was, but when I tore it down, rebuilt it, and re-deployed it, everything started working fine.

Some of the items that changed in the com.myurl.feature.bar feature were a removal of OS specific entries that are apparently legal on a site.xml, but not a category.xml file. I only say this because the editors that Eclipse provides for both have that main difference in them.

The strangest part is that my RCP application could see and use this p2 repository successfully for installing the com.myurl.feature.bar, but tycho couldn't use it to resolve the dependencies at build time... at least not until I changed up the p2 repository for it.

Special note for dgolovin...  As far as I can tell, you definitely can refer to features on a p2 repository and include them in your feature even if they are not a direct part of your build.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to remove the .qualifier.

regards,

Comment: This did not help solve the problem.  The behavior is still the same. The part of the error output is that tells me about the dependency not being found still says it couldn't find version [1.1.4,1.1.5)

Answer (score 0):

Change feature.xml to:

```
<feature>

   ...

<requires>
  <import feature="com.myurl.feature.foo" version="1.0.12" match="compatible"/>
  <import feature="com.myurl.feature.bar" version="1.1.4" match="compatible"/>
</requires>
```

p2 should pick up the latest available features form your p2 repositories.

Comment: I tried this too, and it still did not work.  The command line output shows that the latest items are being found and fetched from the p2 repository.  But after that output, the error still occurs and says that it cannot resolve the project dependencies.

Comment: It happens because included features should be part of the build, they cannot be consumed from p2repo. Try 

    <requires>
      <import feature="com.myurl.feature.foo" version="1.0.12" match="compatible"/>
      <import feature="com.myurl.feature.bar" version="1.1.4" match="compatible"/>
    </requires>

Comment: Isn't that exactly what your answer says to do?  You just repeated it in a comment as far as I can tell.  Am I missing something in the comment that is different from the answer?

Comment: I've updated comment as well, sorry, I forgot to mention it. I changed inclusion to requirement. Inclusion requires referenced features are  built in the same maven reactor. A requirement can be a reference to feature from external p2repo IIRC.

Comment: I've found the problem.  It was with the p2 repository of com.myurl.feature.bar  It was a very strange problem, and I'm not entirely sure what was wrong with it.  I just know that I was at my wits end, so I changed the category.xml file that builds the com.myurl.feature.bar by removing the OS specific notes that seem to belong on a site.xml file, but not a category.xml file. Once I fixed this, then tycho build found the included feature just fine.